# SQLite, Alarm Manager using broadcast class and service class

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I want set an alarm from sqlite db and fetch the alarms on time and date. I have try my best to see it works using extends BroadcastReceiver class and extends Service but i couldnt. here is the code for  the BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
   }
```

}

and for the other class, that is Service class. Here is the code

```
 @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.clear();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

    CharSequence text = format.format(new Date());
    ;
    CharSequence time = formatt.format(new Date());
    ;
    String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM comments_table WHERE time = '" + String.valueOf(time) + "'" +
            "and date =  '%s'", String.valueOf(text) + "");
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    String[] data_me = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        c.moveToNext();
        data_me[i] = c.getString(0);

    }
    c.close();
    db.close();

    AlarmManager[] alarmManager = new AlarmManager[24];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < data_me.length; ii++) {


        alarmManager[ii] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), ii, i, 0);
        alarmManager[ii].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);


    }
}
```

}

Pls, Can someone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start. Based on what you posted, your service will only after the broadcast receiver kicks in. In this case, after the device boots up. Before Android 6 (Marshmallow),   this was enough to handle actions after reboot. This intent doesn't usually suffice as is to handle reboot. 
Are you using a device running Android 6? If yes, you can create a simulated device in you development environment that runs Android 5 or lower just to see that your code works for devices running this Android 5 or lower. Assuming that you want to support  devices running Android 6 or higher,  you'll have to choose a different intent to be handled by your receiver.

To handle the AlarmManager: 
Sorry. Alarmmanager's set method is using the calendar object you created before retrieving the date and time from your database. So when you use it to set the AlarmManager it'll go off then, instead of your saved dates and time FRM the data tabs. You could make a Calendar Array or Array list to store the retrieved dates and then loop through that to set the AlarmManager(s).

As an aside, it's more secure to use the query method for instead of rawQuery in order to prevent a sqlite injection.

**EDIT** Let's walk through your code:

```
 @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
     calender.clear(); //WHY CLEAR CALENDAR? LATER YOU USE IT TO SET THE ALARMMANAGER.
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     SimpleDateFormat formatt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

    CharSequence text = format.format(new Date());
    ; //REMOVE SEMI-COLON
    CharSequence time = formatt.format(new Date());
    ; //REMOVE SEMI-COLON
    String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM comments_table WHERE time = '" + String.valueOf(time) + "'" + "and date =  '%s'", String.valueOf(text) + ""); 
    /*WHAT ARE YOU SELECTING FROM THE DB? 
    *YOU ARE ALREADY USING THE CURRENT TIME AS A PARAMETER; ASSUMEDLY, 
    *YOU'RE NOT RETRIEVING THE DATE AND TIME*/

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null); //WHERE IS YOUR db INITIALIZED & OPENED? ADD APPROPRIATE CODE **BEFORE** MAKING THIS QUERY
    int count = c.getCount();
    String[] data_me = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        c.moveToNext();
        data_me[i] = c.getString(0);

    }
    c.close();
    db.close();

    AlarmManager[] alarmManager = new AlarmManager[24];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < data_me.length; ii++) {


        alarmManager[ii] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyReceiver.class);

         PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), ii, i, 0);
         alarmManager[ii].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a different way you want to initiate the service, specifically, do you want to have the user set a time and/or date (using a TimePicker, for example) for the service to run? In that case you would have a BroadcastReceiver receive the intent and then call the Service, just like you're doing now after a reboot. In fact you can add an intent to your current Receiver class to handle such an intent; just remember to check that any applicable intent-filters are in your manifest file.

If you retrieve dates/time from your query and want to use them to set the AlarmManager, you might want to store the day/time in a Calendar object and place it in a Calendar ArrayList, which you'll loop through when setting up the AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But all this you are saying i have did it and it didn't work thats why I say can you put me through. I am selecting only one column where date equals to current date and time equals to current time. I have did many thinks to see i did this multiple alarm work but I couldn't.  Please! Please!! Please all I need from you is  the live code so that I test run. Thanks